# How to return nested object in NodeJS module.export?

Tags: javascript, node.js, object

Got hanged up on this one.

```
module.exports = {

  capital: {
     name: "Berlin",
     population: 10000,
     area: 15
  },
  country-code: "de",
  langauge: "german"
}
```

Throws error "unexpected token". If I eliminate nesting everything works.

Comment: doubt it ... it's `country-code: "de",` that is invalid - I mean, the error points to that line and specifically the `-` character ...

Comment: that's hilarious! you are right. many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hyphen(-) is not allowed in object names. The parser will interpret it as the subtract operator.

Credit to: @Jaromanda X